# Can't get bluetooth headphones working

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm trying to get bluetooth headphones working with my pi. My setup uses pulseaudio. When I try to load the pulseaudio module I get:

```
$ sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: Module initialization fail
```

syslog tells me:

```
pulseaudio[16157]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-discover": file not found
```

I have pulseaudio-module-bluetooth installed, and in /etc/bluetooth/audio I've set

```
Disable=Socket
Enable=Headset,Source,Sink,Media
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots of hits such as http://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically . Which have you tried?

Comment: @joan have tried lots of things, but the problem is it can't find the module, for which I haven't found a discussion around (or I wouldn't post here...)

Comment: What I did, when I was getting pulse audio errors I couldn't figure out, was did a "apt-get purge pulseaudio" then I copied down all the packages it says it was going to remove. Removed them, then did an install to put them all back. got rid of all the error messages i was getting. though still missing something as can only play short samples via pactl on the headset. Which I believe means it working but it's not being used by anything. so I still need to figure out how to made the headset the default audio out for the system.

Comment: There are issues with a pa5, try compiling pa6 from source and manually install dependencies. I am working on a script to get everything setup. Should be done in the next day or so.

Comment: Alright got it working, see this answer here: it should work for yours as well: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76283/43610