# RPI4 bluetooth device paired and connected and set to audio sink but wont play a sound

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I saw one [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70966/bluetooth-headphones-paired-connected-but-no-audio) with a similar title but the solution program featured did not really answer the question nor work for my case. I am paired and I have my output set to the blue tooth speaker and activated audio sink. The speaker did recognize my device connecting as well since it made a connected sound.

I already tried updating my pi and installing a bunch of programs to try to make it work that i found in various tutorials these:
bluetooth python-gobject python-gobject-2 pi-bluetooth bluez blueman

I set the raspi-config audio setting (in advanced) to auto and the output device to be the JBL speaker. It still does not work, even when playing a wav over aplay. The Audio is supposed to be sinked and the device is recognizing I'm trying to connect or else it would turn off after a while, but nothing happens.

This is the info output of my bluetoothctl:

```
Device AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (public)
Name: JBL GO 2
Alias: JBL GO 2
Class: 0x00200414
Icon: audio-card
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

and systemctl

```
    sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-05-02 14:50:56 CEST; 1h 12min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 608 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─608 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 02 14:50:56 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
May 02 14:50:56 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.23 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
May 02 14:50:56 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.23 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/2
May 02 14:50:56 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
May 02 14:51:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.23 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/3
May 02 15:06:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
May 02 15:06:52 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
May 02 15:06:58 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
May 02 15:26:57 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
May 02 16:02:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[608]: No SDP records found for Headset Voice gateway
```

**solved it my self!**
found this funny article saying [pulseaudio](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) can be purged and [should be purged](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa#troubleshooting) when dealing with blue tooth audio

Comment: Please don't edit into the question that you have solved it. Make an answer with the solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it my self! found this funny article saying pulseaudio can be purged and should be purged when dealing with blue tooth audio (see link in edited question)

```
sudo apt -y purge "pulseaudio*"
```